# Can't install Cassandra using RPM packages for RHEL 9

Tags: cassandra

Error: Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'cassandra': repomd.xml GPG signature verification error: gpgme_op_verify() error: No data

Repo is:

[cassandra]

name=Apache Cassandra

baseurl=https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/41x/noboolean/

gpgcheck=1

repo_gpgcheck=1

gpgkey=https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/KEYS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The issue just got resolved. Please try again.

---

The artifactory access at [jfrog](https://apache.jfrog.io) expired last week - `https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/41x/noboolean/` resolves to `https://apache.jfrog.io/artifactory/cassandra-rpm/41x/noboolean/`

The ASF infra team is working to resolve this problem in [INFRA-25649](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/INFRA-25649).

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with access to JFrog's artifactory (https://apache.jfrog.io) where it reports the 14-day trial has expired which is incorrect.

The issue was escalated to JFrog by [the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) Infrastructure team](https://www.apache.org/dev/infrastructure.html) (see ticket [INFRA-25649](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/INFRA-25649)) which now appears to have been resolved by JFrog. Cheers!